# Position background image in the right half of the screen

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position a background image on the right side of the screen so that on medium screens one could see a half of it and on big ones the whole image (the image should not be scaled). The problem is that there seems to be no way to position left side of the background in the center of the div that has an unknown width.

And I can't use an `img` tag because it will result in a horizontal scrollbar.

EDIT:
It seems that there is no way to position a background the way I wanted, at least with background-position. You can offset a background from either side by writing `background-position: top 50px left 100px`, but you cannot do the same with position `center`. I wonder why.

[image: schema]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working solution. I added another block with an absolute positioning inside the container.

```css
.container {
   margin: 50px;
   padding: 10px 10px;
   position: relative;
   width:400px;
   height:270px;
   border:2px solid red;  
}
.text {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: green;
}
.bg {  
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: 50%; 
 width: 50%; 
 height: 250px;
 background-image: url('http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg');
 background-position: 0 0; 
 background-repeat:no-repeat; 
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
  Text block
  </div>
  <div class="bg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Have you try to set a background size and a background position like so :

```
background-position: 100% 0;
background-size:50%;
```

You can test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/dL2u6co7/

Comment: This always shows the whole image while I need to have only half of it if it doesn't fit (instead of resizing). If it were possible to have an offset from the background position center, it would be enough, but apparently it does not work.